# Javascript Do object literals have prototype property?

Tags: javascript, prototype

When understanding about the 3 broad type of objects in Javascript i.e. Literal, Function objects and Objects from functions, 
I had read somewhere that literal objects do not have prototype property like function objects (or constructors).
Would that be a true statement ?

Reason I am asking this is since we can do;

```
var person = {
fn: 'ABC'
}
person.__proto__ = someObj;
```

Not sure if this setting using "**proto**" is really allowed across all browsers, which is why the statement is not true ?

Also is the same statement true for "objects from functions" ? i.e. when we do "new SomeFunctionObject()"

Answer (score 1):

> I had read somewhere that literal objects do not have prototype property like function objects (or constructors).

This sounds like it's referring to the property named `.prototype`, which is true. A `function` and a `class` will automatically receive a `.prototype` property, which contains one property (`constructor`, pointing to the class/function itself) and inheriting from `Object.prototype`.

The statement in your question is true. Only callable class-like objects - classes and `function`s - automatically receive these sorts of properties. Other objects do not:

```js
class Foo {
}
function Foo2() {
}
const obj = {};

console.log(
  Foo.prototype,
  Foo2.prototype,
  obj.prototype
);
```

Regarding the code in your question, using `__proto__` is permitted, but it's deprecated. As [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto):

> Warning: While `Object.prototype.__proto__` is supported today in most browsers, its existence and exact behavior has only been standardized in the ECMAScript 2015 specification as a legacy feature to ensure compatibility for web browsers. For better support, it is recommended that `Object.getPrototypeOf()` be used instead.

`Object.getPrototypeOf` should be preferred nowdays.

> i.e. when we do "new SomeFunctionObject()"

When you create an instance with `new`, the internal prototype of the new instance will (usually) be same object as the `.prototype` property of the constructor. That is, with the following code:

```
class Foo {
  // anything
}
const f = new Foo();
```

the internal prototype of the `f` instance will be the same object as `Foo.prototype`.

```js
class Foo {
  // anything
}
const f = new Foo();
console.log(
  Object.getPrototypeOf(f) === Foo.prototype,
  f.__proto__ === Foo.prototype,
);
```

The only time where the internal prototype of an instance will *not* be the same as the constructor's `.prototype` would be when the constructor explicitly returns an object, which is somewhat unusual.

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    return {};
  }
}
const f = new Foo();
console.log(
  Object.getPrototypeOf(f) === Foo.prototype,
  f.__proto__ === Foo.prototype,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

functions have a `prototype` property, which inherits from Object.

```js
function Person(last, first, middle){
  // constructors allow private variables that can be shared across methods without the use of `this.` - API developers may accidentally access properties meant to be private in classes, so use constructors
  const proto = Person.prototype;
  if(last !== undefined){
    this.last = last; this.first = first; this.middle = middle;
  }
  this.getFullName = (lastFirst = false)=>{
    const m = this.middle ? ' '+this.middle : ''
    if(lastFirst){
      return this.last+', '+this.first+m;
    }
    return this.first+m+' '+this.last;
  }
  this.setFullName = (last, first, middle)=>{
    proto.last = this.last = last; proto.first = this.first = first; 
    proto.middle = this.middle = middle;
    return this;
  }
}
console.log(typeof Person);
const bob = new Person('Smith', 'Bob', 'Gene');
console.log(bob.getFullName());
const james = new Person('Brown', 'James');
console.log(james.getFullName(true));
bob.setFullName('Static', 'Method', 'like');
const person = new Person;
console.log(person.getFullName()+' -- sort of');
console.log(typeof person);
```

Note that a `new` instance of a constructor returns a `new` Object literal.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `prototype` using this:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, prototype)
```

You can also read docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf).

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly assign a value to an object's **proto**, of course now this object has prototype property. When you just assign a value to an object, currently it has no prototype.This property has some problems on compatibility across browsers.
An object built by `new Con()` certainly has prototype property natively.

Comment: But for an object built by new Con(), it's prototype is automatically set to whatever Con.prototype is set to...Isn't it ? OR can it still be set explicitly ?

Comment: Yes, this is called inheritance in JS. Centainly it can be set explicitly, but it will change the prototype chain when getting some properties or methods from __proto__